# reset IE9 compatibility mode after IE5 has been set

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a webpage that needs to display with at least IE9 (for some calendar display) but the application has forced IE5 before with the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">` tag. (It has been forced on the login page).

So when I try to reforce it in IE9 with `"content="IE=9"` I get the "X-UA-Compatible" META tag ('IE=9') ignored because document mode is already finalized".

I can't modify the first meta tag IE=5 because it is needed for the rest of the application. Is there some other way to force it in IE9?

Thank you anyone who has some hints! :)

Comment: Not possible, as you've stated: "_document mode [has been] already finalized_", and that's it. It was possible to have different document modes in iframes, but even this was removed in IE8, if I can recall the version correctly.

Comment: Ok, thank for your answer anyway !